# Share a background process in django?

Tags: python, django, soap, suds

My django app talks to a SOAP service using the `suds-jurko` library

```
from suds.client import Client
try:
    URL = "http://192.168.12.11/xdwq/some_service.asmx?WSDL"
    client = Client(URL, timeout=30)
except:
    #  Fallback mode
    pass


def get_data(ID):
    try:
        response = client.service.GetData(ID)
        data = response.diffgram.NewDataSet.master
        return data
    except:
        return None
```

In my views

```
data = get_data(ID)
```

The problem is that the service takes quite some time to initialize (~20 seconds). Subsequent requests take upto 3 seconds to return. Whenever the page is requested the webserver (apache with mod_wsgi) takes quite a while to load on some requests.

In my apache configuration

```
WSGIDaemonProcess www.example.com user=hyde group=hyde threads=15 maximum-requests=10000
```

How do I write my code, so that apache (or django) can share a single background process for the SOAP service and minimize the 30s penalty?

I have been reading about celery and other such methods but am unsure how to proceed. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You must create separate background process, using pure python or some third party modules (for example celery, as mentioned) and communicate with that process from django views (using unix or tcp sockets for example).

Also instead of WSGI, you can use different method to serve django application (gunicorn, uwsgi) that will persist in memory, but this is really dirty solution and I don't recommend that.